# Import helper for error handling with confirm window?

Tags: python

I hope to add "confirm window", when user select file which not right extension in blender file selector.

I tried to use `window_manager.popup_menu()`

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty
import os


def ShowMessageBox(message="", title="Message Box", icon='INFO'):
    def drawinfo(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text=message)
    bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(drawinfo, title=title, icon=icon)


class WIF_OP_ImportDazData(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "import_js.dazdata"
    bl_label = "Import Json"
    bl_description = "import rig data to adjust daz bones"
    bl_options = {'UNDO'}

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default='*.json;*.txt',
        options={'HIDDEN'},
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(self.filepath)
        if extension == '.json':
            rigdata = read_json(context, self.filepath)
            rigs = bpy.context.selected_objects
            set_custom_props(rigs, rigdata)
        else:
            print("Select json please!")
            ShowMessageBox("Select JSON please!!", "fail load", "INFO")

        return {'FINISHED'}


# test register and invoke
bpy.utils.register_class(WIF_OP_ImportDazData)

bpy.ops.import_js.dazdata('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Though it work, but there is clear problem.

When user miss select json file, file selector close then return UI. message-box appear, but it located on where user clcik import button only when user stay mouse. then often miss message-box. (they disappear), user can not clear see, if import is cancelled or not. like this

[image: not on file selector]

So what I hope is, show message box on file selector. ideally I hope to use confirm window with custom message (not change UI, but keep file selector)

Is there good way to achive it?  I already try many things but still no success.
(try to call ShowMessageBox in invoke class method etc,,, )

Comment: Would seriously consider not using the menu popup here.  The fileselector is running as a modal operator and execute will pop back to call area.  Would suggest either only globbing for json files, or put your warning message, based on filepath,  in the draw method of the operator.

Comment: Hi batFINGER, yes I almost understand why it not work, and yes I can set globbing json only. but it is for user can easy find json (which saved with same name another format. and image)  then  would you show me simple code, of your second suggesiton?

Comment: Ah I see. I try draw operator, of may use custom label for info, under my panell ui.  thanks.